# Not able to upload or remove image on migrated products in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have migrated products from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2. Now if am uploading a new image then it's not saving. I am also not able to remove the image and gives an error

> The image cannot be removed as it has been assigned to the other image
>   role

As I have also removed rules from all store for the image still it gives the same error while removing the image.

When adding a new image, that particular image is uploading to pub/media/tmp folder but not assigned to the product and pub/media/catalog/product folder as well.

Any fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution which worked from a link

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7647#issuecomment-370726021

But in my case, the value was NULL in catalog_product_entity_varchar for media_gallery attribute.

So did like `DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = 88`

Answer (score 1):

This only occurs when you have `multiple stores` and you have selected `"All Store Views"`.

We got round it by selected each `store and deleting`.

[Reference Link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7647)

Comment: I have tried the same way, the rules were removed but the image is not removing and a new image is also not adding.

Comment: Got the solution from the comments from your given link.

Comment: find your solution then accept my answer